# Unable to download xlsx file

Tags: jmeter

I am developing a JMeter script to download an xlsx file. When the script is executed it is resulting in error.
I checked the JMeter log file and found this :

> 2023-11-03 15:15:22,315 ERROR o.a.j.r.ResultSaver: Error creating sample file for
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (Access is denied)
> at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]  at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
> ~[?:1.8.0_202]    at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
> ~[?:1.8.0_202]    at
> java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:162)
> ~[?:1.8.0_202]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultSaver.saveSample(ResultSaver.java:199)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]  at
> org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultSaver.processSample(ResultSaver.java:166)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]  at
> org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultSaver.sampleOccurred(ResultSaver.java:156)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]  at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:58)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:1037)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:591)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ~[?:1.8.0_202]

On checking the Request Body in View Results Tree I found that the cookie data is sent in the following way :

```
X-CSRF-Token=xxxxx; JSESSIONID=xxxxx.xxxx; ROUTEID=.xxxx; JSESSIONIDSSO=xxxxx
```

Now I checked the same transaction manually. Here I observed that as part of Request Headers Cookie is sent the following way :

```
JSESSIONID=yyyyy.yyyy; X-CSRF-Token=xxxxx; JSESSIONID=xxxxx.xxxx; ajs_user_id=xxxxx; ajs_anonymous_id=xxxxx; style=default; ROUTEID=.xxxx; JSESSIONIDSSO=xxxxx
```

Is the access denied message returned because the JSession ID is not sent ? If yes, how can this be sent as I am not able to figure out where is it actually generated ?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a file permissions issue, seems like your user doesn't have access to the folder where you're trying to save the file.

So either amend [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener and configure it to save the file to the place where your user has write access to or change the [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions) to allow your user to write files to the current folder.

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload & Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)